# Get the XML request sent by Savon gem rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, savon

I want to get  the XML request sent by Savon 2 gem  in rails.

I tried setting `log: true` while initializing the Savon but it doesn't seem to be working as I'm not getting the request that is sent by the Savon in the log file.

I also tried `Savon.client: :pretty_print_xml => true` and `client.config.pretty_print_xml = true` , but they are also not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Rails logger and debug log level by passing appropriate arguments:

```
Savon.client(log: true, logger: Rails.logger, log_level: :debug)
```

Answer (score 0):

To sent XML request using Savon first you need to establish connect.

```
client = Savon.client(wsdl: 'abc.com?wsdl', ssl_verify_mode: :none, basic_auth: ['username', 'password'])
```

then call your desired procedure using this call

```
client.call(:method_name, :message_tag => 'MethodName', :message => {book_id: 1, AuthorName: 'xyz'})
```

It is for rails 3.